# How to properly handle a question about a bug/issue that was fixed

Tags: support, bug-reporting-process

I ask a question about a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359367/search-by-tag-in-mobile-doesnt-work) in mobile site.

I see that there are duplicate question(s) point to my question.

This bug was fixed by someone after few months. what should I do with the unanswered question

Delete/close/add an answer that it's fixed with date/ignore it?

I think the best way is that someone with more details will answer, but what is the proper way of handling fixed issue (specially on meta site)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bug reports on the meta, I believe the proper course of action is to modflag it, and ask if it can get marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), if you're sure it's fixed.

An alternate tag is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), which is applied to bug questions that can't be reproduced. If a dev were to look at your question currently, he might apply that tag.

That way, others can see the bug likely was present, but has been fixed.